# What does this notation mean? $(EX)^{(k)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading some notes on probability theory, and it says $$V(X) = EX^{(2)} - (EX)^{(2)}$$

Why is it using parenthesis around the powers?

Comment: Some context might be helpful.  This looks like the formula for variance of a random variable, which ordinarily would not have those parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Some authors use the notation $x^{(n)}$ to represent a *rising factorial*:
$$
x^{(n)} = x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n-1)
$$
where the RHS is a product of $n$ factors. So $x^{(2)}$ would be an abbreviation for $x(x+1)$. With this interpretation, the quantity $E(X^{(2)})-(EX)^{(2)}$ is indeed equal to the variance of $X$.

Not sure why your notes would want to do this, though.